# How to use function parameters to access an object's element

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs

I am trying to pass a parameter to function to access an object's element but keep getting ReferrenceError:obj is not defined

```js
const obj = {
  'man1': 1,
  'man2': 2,
  'man3': 3
}

function test(i) {
  console.log(obj.man `${i}`)
}
test(1)
test(2)
test(3)
```

Comment: `obj[\`man${i}\`]`

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't produce the error "ReferrenceError:obj is not defined", it produces something along the lines of "TypeError: obj.man is not a function". The error you're describing would occur if you don't have a variable called `obj` defined anywhere, but you're trying to use it